# @ManyToOne mapping in Hibernate not working

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two classes, `Invite` and `Event` with a many-to-one mapping: one event has many invites. Here are the relevant snippets of code/SQL with Hibernate annotations:

**db.Events**

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| event_id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**db.Invites**

```
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| invite_id | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| event_fk  | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**DbInvite.java**

```
@ManyToOne
private DbEvent event;

public DbInvite() {
}

public DbInvite(String name, DbEvent event) {
    this.name = name;
    this.event = event;
}

// getters and setters
```

**DbEvent.java**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "event")
private Set<DbInvite> invites;

public DbEvent() {
}

public DbEvent(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

// getters and setters
```

Finally, I--and this is where most Hibernate examples appear to stop--I create my instances in the following way:

```
DbEvent dbEvent = new DbEvent(name);
DbInvite dbInvite = new DbInvite(name, dbEvent);
```

The error I receive is:

```
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Unknown column 'event_event_id' in 'field list'
```

Where am I going wrong? Where does `event_event_id` come from when the primary key is clearly `event_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify join column for many-to-one, otherwise defaults are assumed by JPA/Hibernate.

Comment: Thanks. For others, I added the annotation `@JoinColumn(name="event_fk")` under the `@ManyToOne` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
DbEvent dbEvent = new DbEvent(name);
//the id is setted in when persist into the db
dbEvent = someMethodThatPersistInDb(dbEvent);
//now the object have the id created in the db now insert the other one
DbInvite dbInvite = new DbInvite(name, dbEvent);
someMethodThatPersistInDb(dbInvite);
```

i hope that can help you, maybe you can post the rest of the mapping class to check the code.